# How to insert a line break after programmatically adding in text to an html element in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

```js
var insertTxt = $("aside p:last-of-type").text().split(" ");
insertTxt.splice(20, 0, 'Chevy Dealers Association ');
$("aside p:last-of-type").text(insertTxt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
  <h2>Client Testimonials</h2>

  <p>Throughout the years we have worked with Vecta Corporation, we have always been amazed at the level of dedication and professionalism that they have provided us and our WGDC products. It is this commitment that has increased both our income and exposure
    exponentially.</p>

  <p>Iona Ford<br> President
  </p>
</aside>
```

I am trying to programmatically add in the string " Chevy Dealers Association " after the word President that is wrapped in a p html tag. The part that I'm having trouble with is adding a line break so that Iona Ford, President, and Chevy Dealers Association is each on their own line. So I am needing to create three separate lines with this one p html tag in Jquery. The results I am getting is displaying it all in one line with commas where I want the line breaks.

Comment: Do you want to add linebreaks using jQuery?  As your HTML shows `br` in it.

Comment: I do want to add them in using jQuery. I can't add in others into my html. I can only have the one.

Answer (score 1):

> The results I am getting is displaying it all in one line with commas where I want the line breaks

The reason for the commas is that after you split the text into an array of strings, you didn't join them back into a large string, so the output is the representation of the array, which has comma as separator.

If you want minimum change to your code and not alter the original html, you can try this.

```
$("aside p:last-of-type").find("br").remove(); // remove old <br> tags as they interfere with text manipulation
var insertTxt = $("aside p:last-of-type").text().split(" ");
insertTxt.push("<br>Chevy Dealers Association"); // add new info, with <br> attached
insertTxt.splice(2, 0, "<br>"); // add <br> after "Ford"
$("aside p:last-of-type").html(insertTxt.join(" ")); // use join to add space back
```

That said, I would recommend you modify the html. For example, you can include  tag for each line and use id to indicate what the line means (e.g. `<span id="boss">Iona Ford</span>`). This might make life a lot easier for future changes to the text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this.

```js
var insertTxt = " <span class='name-span'>Chevy Dealers Association.</span>"

$("aside p:last-of-type").append(insertTxt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
   <h2>Client Testimonials</h2>
   
   <p>Throughout the years we have worked with Vecta Corporation, we have always been amazed at the level of dedication and professionalism that they have provided us and our WGDC products. It is this commitment that has increased both our income and exposure exponentially.</p>
   <p>Iona Ford <br/> President <br/></p>
</aside>
```

If you have more doubts about appending HTML using jQuery visit [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp).

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that there was a better way of doing this, but that really was a simple fix. Instead of putting the whole string like what you had above, I just put the last part so the content wasn't repeated and adjusted the css formatting to make it look like one tag.

Comment: So is it like you just want to change the last part @Aj96 instead of writing whole line again? We can even do that.

Comment: Instead of a p tag, I just used a span tag which allowed me to not have to use the .css command.

Comment: I just edited the snippet. Is this what you were saying? @Aj96

Comment: Yep except I don't need the class attached to the span tag.

Comment: I guess you got the answer then. I added class because span content styling will be easy if required in future.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var insertTxt = "<p>Iona Ford <br/> President <br/> Chevy Dealers Association .</p>"

$("aside p:last-of-type").append(insertTxt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
   <h2>Client Testimonials</h2>
   
   <p>Throughout the years we have worked with Vecta Corporation, we have always been amazed at the level of dedication and professionalism that they have provided us and our WGDC products. It is this commitment that has increased both our income and exposure exponentially.</p>
   
</aside>
```